# \today not showing other than "0"

Tags: titles, texstudio, include

Good evening, I cant figure out how to get the proper date on my first page, and I've already done it without `\maketitle` in the past without problems.
Big document, so nested:

```
root: -> title
      -> any other file needed
      -> the one forgotten file
```

I get the following doc[image]

Main:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % toglie il rientro anglosassone dei paragrafi nuovi
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % non necessario con XeLaTeX
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}   % per selezionare nuovi font
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setlength\evensidemargin{0.0in}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0.0in}
\setlength\textwidth{6.5in}
\setlength\textheight{9.5in}
\setlength\topmargin{-0.5in}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{fr3d-colors}     %% my personal defined colors, will change in something dvipsname
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % permette di avere testo barrato
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titletoc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% For "Outlining pain"
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% \def\Vicodin{Vicodin 150mg}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
%\usepackage{}  % Ps fill

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% For Footer
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.2pt}
%\rhead{Share\LaTeX}
%\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\rhead{\month \year}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\def\day{}
\cfoot{\scriptsize \textit{\textsf{\sffamily\textcopyright} Stupid \textsc{Guy}} 2023}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% For Multiple Columns within Text
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{multicol}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% For Links to Websites
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Hyperlinks
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

\urlstyle{same}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  More customisation
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

%\copyright symbol
\usepackage{textcomp}

% note a piè pagina per altre parti nel corpo di testo
%\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{footmisc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %Title Page
    % \begin{titlepage}
        \include{title}
        \newpage
        \pagestyle{empty}
        \cleardoublepage    %in aggiunta alla paginabianca
    % \end{titlepage}
%   \newpage
%   \thispagestyle{empty}
%   \cleardoublepage    %in aggiunta alla paginabianca
    \include{otherFile}
\end{document}
```

Title.tex, which should show `\today`:

```
\begin{titlepage}   

    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=black] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
        
        %Striscia verticale Green4!25
        \node[rectangle, fill=OliveGreen!30, anchor=south west, minimum width=12mm, minimum height=\paperheight](sidebar) at ($(current page.south west)+(0,0)$){};
    
        \node [anchor=north west, xshift=-1mm, yshift=2mm] (colVert) at ($(sidebar.north east)+(-.02,0)$) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth]{example-image-c}};
        
        %Striscia orizontale 
        \node[rectangle, fill=OliveGreen, anchor=north west, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=24mm](footbar) at ($(colVert.south west)+(0.1,0.12)$){};
        
        \node [anchor=east, text width=\paperwidth, color=white, 
    %   below right=of colVert,
        ] (titolo) at ($(footbar.east)+(-.3,-.0)+(-1.3,0)$)
        {
            \begin{flushright}
                \fontsize{32pt}{32pt}\selectfont \bfseries Spinal surgery
            \end{flushright}
        };
    %   \node (sTitolo) {Diario medico postoperatorio}
    
        \node [anchor=east, text width=\textwidth, color=white, 
        %   below right=of colVert,
        ] (sTitolo) 
        at ($(footbar.east)+(-.3,-2.25)+(-1.3,-0)$)
        {
            \begin{flushright}
                \fontsize{26pt}{30pt}\selectfont  \itshape Journal
            \end{flushright}
        };
        
        \node [anchor=east, text width=\textwidth, color=white, 
        %   below right=of colVert,
        ] (autore) 
        at ($(footbar.east)+(-.3,-5.25)+(-1.3,-0)$)
        {
            \begin{flushright}
                \fontsize{16pt}{20pt}\selectfont  \bfseries \scshape Stupid guy
            \end{flushright}
        };
        
        \node [anchor=east, text width=\textwidth, color=white, 
        %   below right=of colVert,
        ] (info) 
        at ($(footbar.east)+(-.3,-15.75)+(-1.3,-0)$)
        {
    %       \raggedright
            \begin{flushright}
                \fontsize{12pt}{18pt}\selectfont  
                    \begin{tabular}{rl}
    %                   %more text as Admission date ,ecc
                        \textbf{v 1.16}&   \today   \\
                    \end{tabular}
            \end{flushright}
        };
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}
```

And finally the simplified version with 5 different file looking like this one that will also come togheter into the main or root file:

```
\section*{1st day}
\blindtext

\section*{2nd day}
\begin{wrapfigure}[22]{l}{0.63\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[\width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext
\blindtext

\subsection*{3rd day}
\begin{wrapfigure}[22]{l}{0.63\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[\width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section*{4th day}
\begin{wrapfigure}[22]{l}{0.63\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[\width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext
\blindtext

\subsection*{6th day}
\begin{wrapfigure}[22]{l}{0.63\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[\width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext
\blindtext

and so on for the other important days
```

Yes the wrapfig is used with PS tricks to highlight the important stuff, and a lot of packages for further plotting some pgf graph, and I'm also working on a war to get `siunitx` command `\qty{}{}` to display number accordingly with the text font, but that's not for his post.

I've alredy tried to create a phony `\maketitle`, where I intended to put mine, nothing, the `\date{\today}` also didn't work, so I tried with `titlepage env` inside and outside the included file (look at all those commented lines).

2 weeks ago I upgraded TeXstudio from 4.6.3 to 4.7.0 version, if it matters.

Thanks for all the help.

I did some work around this personal journal template I found in overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/personal-journal-template/cnhkpjpfkrdn), reading @campa comment's, I got the suspicion the recursive redefinition of \day in the journal might affect the \today behaviour. Am I correct?

If that's the case I deserve to lose 100 points rep as I didn't notice something that obvious....
I'm so sorry for making you waste time on my stupid question.

Comment: Please trim this down to something manageable.  Remove everything not related to showing the date, and then remove all packages not related to what's left.

Comment: If you are asking about `\today` surely you can cut this down to an example of three or four lines not  requiring asking people to trace massive packages such as tikz and pstricks

Comment: I won't even try to put an example together but `\rhead{\month\quad\year}` looks very suspicious. Please don't ignore errors.

Comment: @campa I started with this template (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/personal-journal-template/cnhkpjpfkrdn) and personalized it a bit. Is this problem related about the periodic REdefinition of \day, a reserved latex comand?

Comment: `\day`, `\month`, and `\year` are TeX primitive integer registers. If you want to *print* them, you should use `\number\month\quad\number\year`, and not `\month\quad\year`. And `\def\day{}` is bound to wreak havoc as soon as you use `\today`.

Comment: @campa Yes I figured it out the hard way thanks to you, but I sheepedly followed that template. Thanks a lot again

Comment: @campa Now that you're there, is there something that could go prevent me from using \Day \weekDay \Month and \Year? inside my journal? It's late and I couldn't remember whether definition are Cap sensitive in latex?

Comment: @Fr3d -- Definitions *are* case sensitive in LaTeX; this is built into TeX, and there's no good reason to change it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, I was just planning to use the one with the capital letter, in order to get it working and show me the `\today` date on the cover/title page,  and was wondering if it was a better idea or not.

Answer (score 0):

Look at @campa comment, I sheepely followed an overleaf template.......
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/personal-journal-template/cnhkpjpfkrdn

11th commandment, never trust anything on the internet.
I'm so sorry to have all of you wasted an hour to help me, thanks a lot folks

So new definition with a capital letter solved the problem, untill it didn't.... But finally the culprit was `\def\day{}` in the `fancyhf` part of the the preamble. Now it works as intended!

Yuhuuuuu

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and your 11th commandment.  Some places on the internet *do* try to be trustworthy, and the challenge is to learn which ones.  Overleaf tries, so if you find something misleading in their documentation, report it to them, and I'm sure they'll try to fix it.  If they don't, ping me, and I'll nag the people I know there to find out why.

Comment: Used the "Contect Us" button on the overleaf platform, and sent my complaint about a questionable template, attaching the link of the template. Now I'll wait an answer from them. Thanks again for the help @barbarabeeton

Comment: Note that the templates you can find at Overleaf, at least to my knowledge, are mostly created by various users who have different levels of expertise when it comes to TeX. Everything that is user generated and not sufficiently tested by a larger community should be handled with care. But it is a good idea to notify Overleaf of bugs in these templates.